# Advantages of WebServiceGatewaySupport vs WebServiceTemplate

Tags: spring-ws

I have to implement a webservice client using Spring WS.

I've read the documentation at http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html but it's not clear to me what are the advantages of extending [`WebServiceGatewaySupport`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/support/WebServiceGatewaySupport.html) versus directly using [`WebServiceTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html) in my service class.

As far as I can tell from the source, the `WebServiceGatewaySupport` only has a couple of wrapper methods for the `WebServiceTemplate` and some initialization support.

So why should I extend `WebServiceGatewaySupport` instead of directly using a `WebServiceTemplate` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this sums it all up (found in the client reference you linked):

> Alternatively, consider deriving from Spring-WS's
>   WebServiceGatewaySupport convenience base class, which exposes
>   convenient bean properties to enable easy configuration. (You do not
>   have to extend this base class... it is provided as a convenience
>   class only.)

So, if the `WebserviceTemplate` offers all you need, that'll probably suffice. If you need anything extra you can use the `WebServiceGatewaySupport` as an example on how to wrap your own convenience methods around the `WebserviceTemplate`.

In my client software, I just configure the `WebserviceTemplate` in my [`@Configuration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) class like this:

```
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
    WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();
    template.setMessageFactory(messageFactory());
    template.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    template.setMarshaller(marshaller());
    template.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
    template.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[] {interceptor()});

    return template;
}
```

(All the method calls are references to other methods in the configuration which aren't that relevant in this example).
I can use that bean everywhere in my code to send messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll give you the bounty if there's no better reply in 24h.

Comment: What do they mean "you do not have to extend this base class.."? The class is abstract. You need to extend it in order to use it.

Comment: @MehdiCharife, I'm not sure, it's still in the spring-ws documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html - I haven't worked with spring-ws in a while. Since this answer is 10 years old, things might have changed ;-)